# Python: Multiple threads that can cross-communicate

Tags: python, multithreading, loops

I want to run two separate functions that loop at constant time intervals, that run at the same time.

Function1 needs to loop every 60 seconds. I then want to trigger the start of Function2 from Function1. Function2 then loops every 5 seconds. At a certain point I want to stop Function2.

[image: Flow diagram]

What is the best solution for this? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Avoid posting images. Even pseudo-code would be much better. Please edit your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do this using [`multiprocessing.Process`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process):

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def function1():
    # ... Initiate loop
    child_process = Process(target=function2)
    child_process.daemon = True # We want function2 to be terminated if function1 exits for some reason
    child_process.start()
    # ... Continue loop execution as normal
    # ... After some time
    child_process.terminate() # This will terminate function2
    # ...
    return

def function2():
    # ... Loop and do stuff
    return

function1()
```

If you want to synchronize both processes, you can use a [`Lock`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Lock):

```
from threading import Lock

global_lock = Lock()

def function1():
    child_process = Process(target=function2)
    child_process.daemon = True 
    child_process.start()
    with global_lock:
         # Lock acquired
         print('function1')
    # Lock released
def function2():
    with global_lock:
         # Lock acquired
         print('function2')
    # Lock released

function1()
```

With this approach you can guarantee that the print statements will never be executed in parallel, but rather sequentially

Comment: Can time.sleep(X) be used with both functions?

Comment: @Calum You can, but note that `time.sleep` will block the current thread, i.e. it will block the current process. In your case, `time.sleep` on `function1` will only block `function1`, `function2` will continue unaffected.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [condition variable](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#condition-objects) to signal from one thread to another thread.